# start cssbased slider automatically?

Tags: css, slider

Im trying to create a css only slider, and it works great. however, I want it to start automatically and have a automatic transition. Is this possible trough css?

Codepen with the html and css:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaQGvp

```
   <div class="slider"> 
    <input type="radio" id="control1" name="controls" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="control1"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="control2" name="controls"/>
    <label for="control2"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="control3" name="controls"/>
    <label for="control3"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="control4" name="controls"/>
    <label for="control4"></label>
 <div class="sliderinner">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/aAExlOn.jpg" />

            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/aAExlOn.jpg" />

            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/aAExlOn.jpg" />

            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/aAExlOn.jpg" />

            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way out:

```
@keyframes round{   
  25%{opacity:1;}
  40%{opacity:0;}
} 

.auto{
  position:absolute;
  animation:round 16s infinite;
  opacity:0;
 }

img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0s;}
img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:4s;}
img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:8s;}
img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:12s;}
```

Add class `auto` to your images and try it out.

```
Let me know if you are looking for something else :)
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look to this :

> [**Live demo**](http://codepen.io/zerubeus/pen/jEZXzw)

```
input[type=radio]#control1:checked~.sliderinner>ul { -webkit-animation: test infinite 10s alternate;
  animation: test infinite 10s alternate; }
.slider input[type=radio]#control2:checked~.sliderinner>ul { left: -100% }
.slider input[type=radio]#control3:checked~.sliderinner>ul { left: -200% }
.slider input[type=radio]#control4:checked~.sliderinner>ul { left: -300% }
.slider input[type=radio]#control5:checked~.sliderinner>ul { left: -400% }

@-webkit-keyframes test {
   0% {
      left: 0;
    }

    10% {
      left: -100%;
    }

    30% {
      left: -200%
    }

    90% {
      left: -300%;
    }

    100% {
      left: -400%;
    }
}
@keyframes test {
   0% {
      left: 0;
    }

    10% {
      left: -100%;
    }

    30% {
      left: -200%
    }

    90% {
      left: -300%;
    }

    100% {
      left: -400%;
    }
}
```

this is not complete but it can be better , this is only CSS solution using `key frames`

you can follow my example and make it look better , good luck

Comment: Pretty cool! Is it possible to make the slide only go one way and start over somehow?

Comment: yes you can use from/to in the key frame here is a good tutorial about keyframes http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/ and Please accept this (click the tick) if this solved your issue so others may learn from it in the future